" I got her hair cut. " VS " I got her a haircut. "
If you have an elderly mom who can't go out by herself, and if you take her to a barber's, arrange the haircut model, style, etc. and pay and bring her back home, and on your way back home, if you bump into a friend and he asks you how are you, where are coming from, etc should I say:
- I got her hair cut.
OR,
- I got her a haircut.
Although the second one seems rare, I have been told that the second one is better for this situation, because it reflects the whole process of what we have been doing - rather than just the simple hair cut - I mean, the whole process of my taking her out, walking her to the barber, deciding on hairstyle, bringing her back etc.
Is that correct?

Only men have 'haircuts' or go to a 'barber'.

I would dispute the assertion that 'only men have haircuts', but you might say "I've been taking Mum to get her hair cut" or "...to the hairdresser's".

Or "I took my mom to get her hair cut".

"I got her hair cut"  has a somewhat harsh  tone. Routine maintenance. Almost like an oil change for the car. It could be followed by "and later I'm going to hose her down."

I don't think there's much difference, but this seems to be a matter of opinion rather than anything with a factual answer. There are many alternative phrases ("got her hair styled", "got a new hairdo/cut"...), and you could even say "She got her hair cut" rather than "I got her hair cut" so it's more an issue of what precise nuance you want to communicate, and even then there's no guarantee the nuance will be picked up.

But Michael Harvey is half-right: barber is usually for men's hair; a hairdresser or stylist cuts a woman's hair. (Although that's not really the question.)

My (female) barber in Loulé (not a well known city in the Algarve) cuts men's hair but will also cut my wife's and that of any other women who just want a cut. Time-honoured distinctions are everywhere crumbling.

@StuartF - Yes, I wasn't disputing that part of Michael's answer. A barber really means a man who shaves other men, though of course they do hairdressing as well.

"Haircut" is a noun. It refers to the act or process of cutting and shaping the hair.
"hair cut" is a noun phrase comprising the noun hair and the verb cut. It means the cutting of hair.
In most contexts, the meaning of both your examples would be understood the same way. Just like "I went swimming" and "I went for a swim" mean the same thing.
However, there could be a difference in some specific contexts. "A haircut" is an intentional act of cutting the hair into a style. If someone's hair was cut in some accidental way, you likely wouldn't say it was "a haircut". For this reason "a haircut" probably sounds better, although if you said "hair cut" it is highly unlikely anyone would assume anything other than the intentional styling of hair unless you stated otherwise.
